# How can users generate their own reports on SQL Server Reporting Service based on their access level?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, subscription

I work for a Distribution company and we have different types of users (e.g. Sales Manager, Financial Analyst, etc.) with different access levels across our local network. I am stuck with the following problems and would really appreciate it if you could help me out:

- What are the tools that could give us the ability to share our
  reports (on SSRS) with our users in our network (based on their
  access level)? (Is there anything better than Sharepoint? Or Is SSRS
  enough?)
- More importantly, we want each user (based on their access
  level) to be able to view, filter, and export their own reports
  dynamically.
- Getting their activity log would be of great value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you Grant access at SQL SERVER level that will do it.